# XML TO PHP Covnvertion

Tags: php, xml

I have the xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<santamaster>

<paths>
<thename >Agamemnonas</thename>
<soundpath startAt="0">sounds/namesounds/agamemnonas.mp3</soundpath>
<theage startAt="5000">sounds/ages/5.mp3</theage>
<theplace startAt="10000">sounds/places/ipiros.mp3</theplace>
<everyday startAt="15000">sounds/everyday/bravekid.mp3</everyday>
<youwill startAt="20000">sounds/youwill/listeryourparents.mp3</youwill>
<pic1 startAt="0">images/pic1.jpg</pic1>
<pic2 startAt="5000">images/pic2.jpg</pic2>
<pic3 startAt="10000">images/pic3.jpg</pic3>
<videofile>myvideo.mp4</videofile>
</paths>

</santamaster>
```

i am trying to echo this code through a php file and some variables:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
echo'
<santamaster>

<paths>
<thename >Irene</thename>
<soundpath startAt="0">"'.$_SESSION['audiolink'].'"</soundpath>
<theage startAt="5000">"'.$_SESSION['age'].'"</theage>
<theplace startAt="10000">"'.$_SESSION['thelocation'].'"</theplace>
<everyday startAt="15000">"'.$_SESSION['dailylife'].'"</everyday>
<youwill startAt="20000">"'.$_SESSION['YOU_WILL'].'"</youwill>
<pic1 startAt="0">"'.$_SESSION['pimagepath'].'"</pic1>
<pic2 startAt="5000">"'.$_SESSION['eoneimagepath'].'"</pic2>
<pic3 startAt="10000">"'.$_SESSION['etwoimagepath'].'"</pic3>
<videofile>santavideo/sample.mp4</videofile>
</paths>

</santamaster>';

?>
```

But nothing happend..

[image]

Its importan to load the variables in xml through session, the session variables are working.. I need it to load it in an flash movie!

Thank you all!

Comment: It looks like there's no data in the `$_SESSION` vars.  `var_dump($_SESSION)`, is there anything there?

Comment: i have setup a sessions php file to check if my sessions are working and they are on. if you look my populated xml you will notice that the  <soundpath startAt="0"/> isnt closed with </soundpath>

Comment: if i remove sessions and set variables $h = "hello"; and put it inside of a child nothing appears again!

Comment: You're looking at the browser's rendering instead of the raw source.  View it, and you'll see it's actually `<soundpath startAt="0"></soundpath>`.  Get rid of the XML, make the only output the `var_dump($_SESSION)`, and you'll see your problem.

Comment: i echoed var_dump($_SESSION) in a clear php file and i gor NULL.

Comment: Correct Brad, i forgot to call all my $_SESSION['xxx']; :-)